# Python Selenium: Find an input location where unique identifier goes blank when input is selected

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select the User ID & password inputs on this page: https://kite.zerodha.com/

The User ID input element looks like this:

`<input type="text" placeholder="User ID" autocorrect="off" maxlength="6" autofocus="autofocus" autocapitalize="characters" animate="true" label="" rules="[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8">`

However, when I click into the cell, it becomes this:

`<input type="text" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" maxlength="6" autofocus="autofocus" autocapitalize="characters" animate="true" label="" rules="[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8">`

Essentially, the only identifiable element "placeholder" becomes blank and my script throws an error. It looks like they are running a script that makes it blank on purpose.

How can I select these fields in Selenium?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following xpath.

```
driver.get("https://kite.zerodha.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[text()='User ID']/following::input[1]"))).send_keys("KK")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[text()='Password']/following::input[1]"))).send_keys("KK1234")
```

---

Or use following css selector.

```
driver.get("https://kite.zerodha.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".uppercase.su-input-group>input"))).send_keys("KK")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class='su-input-group']>input"))).send_keys("KK1234")
```

You need to import following librareis.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Browser snapshot.

[image]